# Chainlink submit_tx Error: cannot send transaction on chain ID

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, go-ethereum, chainlink

Followed the [Fulfilling Requests documentation](https://docs.chain.link/docs/fulfilling-requests/) on Chainlink, and got the following error. [Image: Chainlink Operator Overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B5Q0M.png)

**Chainlink CLI - [DEBUG]:**

```
2022-03-19T03:17:42.410Z [DEBUG] Error in transaction, rolling back: cannot send transaction on chain ID 122022; eth key with address 0x122D45338AFB7198a34054eEC9AB03e1d4611674 is pegged to chain ID 4 pg/transaction.go:114            evmChainID=122022 logger=1.2.0@unset.EVM.BulletproofTxManager 
2022-03-19T03:17:42.411Z [DEBUG] Pipeline task completed                            pipeline/runner.go:412           attempt=0 contract=0x9DA0F694B15525E32cb2A1E1A44854854BD2E987 externalJobID=83a29336-ebbb-42cb-8cc1-47b2eb69ff1b jobID=0 logger=1.2.0@unset.DirectRequest.DirectRequest resultError=while creating transaction: cannot send transaction on chain ID 122022; eth key with address 0x122D45338AFB7198a34054eEC9AB03e1d4611674 is pegged to chain ID 4: task run failed resultErrorVerbose=task run failed
```

I am using Geth to run a local Ethereum blockchain with a private chain id (122022), and running a Chainlink Docker container. Provided I am using go-ethereum, I have set the advised flags advised by Chainlink in their [configuration documentation](https://docs.chain.link/docs/configuration-variables/#go-ethereum):

```
--rpc.gascap=0 --rpc.txfeecap=0
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Chainlink Operator - JSON Results:**

```
{
  "__typename": "JobRun",
  "id": "8",
  "allErrors": [
    "while creating transaction: cannot send transaction on chain ID 122022; eth key with address 0x122D45338AFB7198a34054eEC9AB03e1d4611674 is pegged to chain ID 4: task run failed"
  ],
  "createdAt": "2022-03-19T03:23:01.93773Z",
  "fatalErrors": [
    "while creating transaction: cannot send transaction on chain ID 122022; eth key with address 0x122D45338AFB7198a34054eEC9AB03e1d4611674 is pegged to chain ID 4: task run failed"
  ],
  "finishedAt": "2022-03-19T03:23:02.390829Z",
  "job": {
    "__typename": "Job",
    "id": "88",
    "name": "Test",
    "observationSource": " decode_log [type="ethabidecodelog" abi="OracleRequest(bytes32 indexed specId, address requester, bytes32 requestId, uint256 payment, address callbackAddr, bytes4 callbackFunctionId, uint256 cancelExpiration, uint256 dataVersion, bytes data)" data="$(jobRun.logData)" topics="$(jobRun.logTopics)"] decode_cbor [type="cborparse" data="$(decode_log.data)"] fetch [type="http" method=GET url="$(decode_cbor.get)"] parse [type="jsonparse" path="$(decode_cbor.path)" data="$(fetch)"] multiply [type="multiply" input="$(parse)" times=100] encode_data [type="ethabiencode" abi="(uint256 value)" data="{ \"value\": $(multiply) }"] encode_tx [type="ethabiencode" abi="fulfillOracleRequest(bytes32 requestId, uint256 payment, address callbackAddress, bytes4 callbackFunctionId, uint256 expiration, bytes32 data)" data="{\"requestId\": $(decode_log.requestId), \"payment\": $(decode_log.payment), \"callbackAddress\": $(decode_log.callbackAddr), \"callbackFunctionId\": $(decode_log.callbackFunctionId), \"expiration\": $(decode_log.cancelExpiration), \"data\": $(encode_data)}" ] submit_tx [type="ethtx" to="0x9DA0F694B15525E32cb2A1E1A44854854BD2E987" data="$(encode_tx)"] decode_log -> decode_cbor -> fetch -> parse -> multiply -> encode_data -> encode_tx -> submit_tx "
  },
  "status": "ERRORED",
  "inputs": {
    "jobRun": {
      "logAddress": "0x9da0f694b15525e32cb2a1e1a44854854bd2e987",
      "logBlockHash": "0x4e66a31c2ab22283202184fc8732fc3f3e9f575f3ddd128fdcb860255126f090",
      "logBlockNumber": 70707,
      "logData": "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA3QFSSOUtjq25xPwm7C684fiuHFZthyAXrAtvjqeFJoyZaKtvFAs0w78YtEb1iWf9DJAI3gAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA3gtrOnZAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA3QFSSOUtjq25xPwm7C684fiuHFaSzarzAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABiNU3BAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABWY2dldHg/aHR0cHM6Ly9taW4tYXBpLmNyeXB0b2NvbXBhcmUuY29tL2RhdGEvcHJpY2U/ZnN5bT1FVEgmdHN5bXM9VVNEZHBhdGhjVVNEZXRpbWVzGGQ=",
      "logTopics": [
        "0xd8d7ecc4800d25fa53ce0372f13a416d98907a7ef3d8d3bdd79cf4fe75529c65",
        "0x3339393033666661636336343430343138353864343737623137636332313766"
      ],
      "logTxHash": "0xd30351886659688c9c4442a3ac8aef3e764014ce29e5f498130a0f7cd0958bc4",
      "meta": {
        "oracleRequest": {
          "callbackAddr": "0xDd015248e52D8eADb9c4fc26eC2EbCe1f8ae1c56",
          "callbackFunctionId": "0x92cdaaf3",
          "cancelExpiration": "1647660481",
          "data": "0x63676574783f68747470733a2f2f6d696e2d6170692e63727970746f636f6d706172652e636f6d2f646174612f70726963653f6673796d3d455448267473796d733d5553446470617468635553446574696d65731864",
          "dataVersion": "1",
          "payment": "1000000000000000000",
          "requestId": "0x6d872017ac0b6f8ea785268c9968ab6f140b34c3bf18b446f58967fd0c9008de",
          "requester": "0xDd015248e52D8eADb9c4fc26eC2EbCe1f8ae1c56",
          "specId": "0x3339393033666661636336343430343138353864343737623137636332313766"
        }
      }
    },
    "jobSpec": {
      "databaseID": 88,
      "externalJobID": "39903ffa-cc64-4041-858d-477b17cc217f",
      "name": "Test"
    }
  },
  "outputs": [
    null
  ],
  "taskRuns": [
    {
      "__typename": "TaskRun",
      "id": "a55ffb4e-69c6-4f9a-b1d6-d621d915517e",
      "createdAt": "2022-03-19T03:23:01.939182Z",
      "dotID": "submit_tx",
      "error": "while creating transaction: cannot send transaction on chain ID 122022; eth key with address 0x122D45338AFB7198a34054eEC9AB03e1d4611674 is pegged to chain ID 4: task run failed",
      "finishedAt": "2022-03-19T03:23:02.390795Z",
      "output": "null",
      "type": "ethtx"
    },
    {
      "__typename": "TaskRun",
      "id": "10dabecd-11b5-4921-85c9-3bcdd132d1b0",
      "createdAt": "2022-03-19T03:23:01.943156Z",
      "dotID": "decode_log",
      "error": null,
      "finishedAt": "2022-03-19T03:23:01.943428Z",
      "output": "{"callbackAddr":"0xdd015248e52d8eadb9c4fc26ec2ebce1f8ae1c56","callbackFunctionId":[146,205,170,243],"cancelExpiration":1647660481,"data":"Y2dldHg/aHR0cHM6Ly9taW4tYXBpLmNyeXB0b2NvbXBhcmUuY29tL2RhdGEvcHJpY2U/ZnN5bT1FVEgmdHN5bXM9VVNEZHBhdGhjVVNEZXRpbWVzGGQ=","dataVersion":1,"payment":1000000000000000000,"requestId":[109,135,32,23,172,11,111,142,167,133,38,140,153,104,171,111,20,11,52,195,191,24,180,70,245,137,103,253,12,144,8,222],"requester":"0xdd015248e52d8eadb9c4fc26ec2ebce1f8ae1c56","specId":[51,57,57,48,51,102,102,97,99,99,54,52,52,48,52,49,56,53,56,100,52,55,55,98,49,55,99,99,50,49,55,102]}",
      "type": "ethabidecodelog"
    },
    {
      "__typename": "TaskRun",
      "id": "9b3a8e75-309a-4f08-8ec2-ff7bc13e1951",
      "createdAt": "2022-03-19T03:23:01.943566Z",
      "dotID": "decode_cbor",
      "error": null,
      "finishedAt": "2022-03-19T03:23:01.943752Z",
      "output": "{"get":"https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=ETH\u0026tsyms=USD","path":"USD","times":100}",
      "type": "cborparse"
    },
    {
      "__typename": "TaskRun",
      "id": "636d6c93-dbe2-4929-ae2a-cda642c165fd",
      "createdAt": "2022-03-19T03:23:01.943837Z",
      "dotID": "fetch",
      "error": null,
      "finishedAt": "2022-03-19T03:23:02.387093Z",
      "output": ""{\"USD\":2946.33}"",
      "type": "http"
    },
    {
      "__typename": "TaskRun",
      "id": "f6d2778f-008e-45ea-8e7c-4399ba829bea",
      "createdAt": "2022-03-19T03:23:02.387223Z",
      "dotID": "parse",
      "error": null,
      "finishedAt": "2022-03-19T03:23:02.387411Z",
      "output": "2946.33",
      "type": "jsonparse"
    },
    {
      "__typename": "TaskRun",
      "id": "da229b9e-1821-406b-a5f5-2d129b488ffc",
      "createdAt": "2022-03-19T03:23:02.387508Z",
      "dotID": "multiply",
      "error": null,
      "finishedAt": "2022-03-19T03:23:02.387662Z",
      "output": ""294633"",
      "type": "multiply"
    },
    {
      "__typename": "TaskRun",
      "id": "487078fb-53b0-4e5d-b3f2-01f74f143fab",
      "createdAt": "2022-03-19T03:23:02.387746Z",
      "dotID": "encode_data",
      "error": null,
      "finishedAt": "2022-03-19T03:23:02.387971Z",
      "output": ""0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000047ee9"",
      "type": "ethabiencode"
    },
    {
      "__typename": "TaskRun",
      "id": "aca6aa4b-330b-4a2b-a0c3-3990204e4652",
      "createdAt": "2022-03-19T03:23:02.388082Z",
      "dotID": "encode_tx",
      "error": null,
      "finishedAt": "2022-03-19T03:23:02.388411Z",
      "output": ""0x4ab0d1906d872017ac0b6f8ea785268c9968ab6f140b34c3bf18b446f58967fd0c9008de0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000de0b6b3a7640000000000000000000000000000dd015248e52d8eadb9c4fc26ec2ebce1f8ae1c5692cdaaf3000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000062354dc10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000047ee9"",
      "type": "ethabiencode"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Wondering if you can make this an issue on the documentation repo? https://github.com/smartcontractkit/documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recreated (DROP -> CREATE) the PostgreSQL database because prior to adding a new chain within chainlink, it was initially configured to another chain/network id, which seemingly threw these errors.